# Maven build outside eclipse, very time consuming

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

My current Setup:

1. I have Ecliple Mars installed on Windows 10
2. I have some repositories checked out in my Project explorer which I basically use for any code changes, debugging purpose.
3. I have tomcat installed in C directory and have its path configured in the Servers section of eclipse.
4. So, every time I do any code changes in eclipse, I manually go into the eclipse workspace, and do the `maven` build using the following command`mvn -Plocal -DskipTests=true clean install`, and then manually copy the `war` generated in the target folder into the `webapps` directory of my tomcat.
5. After doing all these, I start my tomcat in debug mode `catalina jpda start` and then setup `Remote Java Application` in eclipse for a particular module.
6. I can then setup breakpoints and see the changes in the debugger.

I am wondering , all of the above steps are time consuming if I have to do frequent code changes and then debug something in Debug mode in eclipse as I have to repeat steps 4 to 6 again and again for any code changes.

Could anyone tell me if there is a quick way to achieve the same goal?

Comment: Yes it really is. If you have your tomcat configured into eclipse you don't need the outside eclipse steps at all. Just start your tomcat IN eclipse on the debug mode.

Comment: Why bother with all this mess? Either 1) use your IDE properly, or 2) use Maven properly.

Comment: @BoristheSpider In the context of Eclipse, are you implicitly trying to say that I should use `m2e`  plugin for maven build?

Comment: @John Do you not use m2e in Eclipse? Integrate the run into Eclipse there exists a Tomcat plugin for Eclipse which supports those scenarios....directly within Eclipse...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run application dirrectly from maven via maven-{your_servlet_container}-plugin (maven-tomcat-plugin, maven-jetty-plugin, etc.). you can also specify debug mode there, so all you need to do is just run maven and connect in eclipse to remote app.
set ENV variable for always run maven in debug:

```
set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000
```

(unset by setting this value to empty string)

with env variable:

```
mvn -Plocal -DskipTests=true clean tomcat7:run
```

or run `mvnDebug`:

```
mvnDebug -Plocal -DskipTests=true clean tomcat7:run
```

Comment: "by running application dirrectly from maven", you mean, I should be working from windows command prompt?

Comment: but you still run `catalina jpda start` from there. left the job for maven. he knows better.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your tomcat configured with eclipse properly, then you don't need to perform all these steps. I am not sure if you want to automate all these steps from outside. if yes, then either you can automate above steps with writing all in a batch file & triggering all steps with it (not a standard way) or using maven plugins to automate most of these steps.

Hope this information will help...